# What if we want to send the data computed in one screen's ViewModel, before popping the screen out, to next screen's ViewModel, how will we achieve it

Tags: flutter, mvvm, clean-architecture, data-sharing

For e.g., when we hit log in api and get accurate response back from it, then we pop the Log In Screen out, but we do need to send data received to multiple other screens like displaying user information i.e. username on the screen, what will be the most efficient way to transfer data between screens,

I think that we can achieve this by dependency injection or by using stream controllers maybe, but what is the most efficient way to do this.

p.s. I'm using Flutter for app development!

I just want to know the efficient way to do the task

Comment: I don't know much about flutter, but what you talk about is application state management. A google search lead me to https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro. I guess you will find your answer there.

Comment: I figured it out, it's better to go with Provider/Bloc State Managements. Thanks!